# Does the slow over rate rule apply only up to the start of the final over?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

After the [India vs Bangladesh match](http://www.icc-cricket.com/world-t20/match/worldt20-2016/25) at the 2016 World T20, MS Dhoni, referring to the slow over rate rule, said

> I knew that once 20th over started, you can take as much time as
>   possible, you can't get fined for it. I had the luxury of spending a
>   bit of time.

(reported by the [*Times of India*](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/icc-world-t20-2016/top-stories/Dhoni-plots-Indias-great-escape-in-Bangalore-heartstopper/articleshow/51538576.cms)). Does this rule apply to all ICC cricket, or is it something specific to the World T20?

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing in the [ICC World Twenty20 2016 Playing Conditions](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/56bb2a65a7f53-Men's%20World%20T20%20Playing%20Conditions%20Clean%20Copy%20090216.pdf) which would support Dhoni's comment. The over rate regulations are defined Law 16.2 and and simply say that

> The actual over rate will be calculated at the end of the match by the umpires

and make no mention of anything like "the time taken shall only be up to the start of the final over". It is possibly worth noting that the World T20 regulations do include

> an additional allowance of 1 minute will be given for each of the 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th wickets taken during an innings.

so India will have been given an allowance of three minutes for the wickets which did fall in the last over.

Comment: I cant find the reference but the standard is that you have to have started the last over by a certain point in time to comply with the over rate.